# Same flow for multiple document libraries - alternatives to export/import?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, flow

i have several document libraries, for which i would like to get a notification when an element has been uploaded/modified/deleted. Using Flow, this is absolutely no problem and works like a charm. The only downside: this only works for the specific library i created the flow for.

Now after searching and browsing different sites i found a solution suggesting that i should use the export/import feature, which of course is a valid way, but doing this for more than two or three libraries seems ... crazy, not to mention the effort involved in making changes to the flow(s).

But to the real question: does anyone know whether there are alternative ways of achieving this?

Thanks a lot!
Dany

Comment: Great question :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's possible, but you could use flow itself to export and import flows. And maybe you could build a loop to deploy it to several libraries with the library as parameter.

This post describes options to extract and deploy flows with flow: http://johnliu.net/blog/2017/12/you-must-copy-all-your-flows-to-sharepoint-simple-ideas-are-the-most-brilliant

Maybe that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of the same challenge, as I was looking for all items of Content type X that have been updated within the last 24 hours across a number of site collections . Since I had no way to ensure that the Flow was added to each list/library using that content type I switched to a Search based approach and a timer job (Azure function).